# How can I use localize template tag with date filter in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

According to Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#localize), the localize template tag allows for more fine-grained control of localization in templates than the general USE_L10N = True setting.

However, turning localize on doesn't produce the same result as setting USE_L10N = True when combined with the date filter.

```
# USE_L10N = True in settings.py

{% load l10n %}
{{some_datetime_value|date}}

# Date is shown and localized
```

vs

```
# USE_L10N = False in settings.py

{% load l10n %}
{% localize on %}
{{some_datetime_value|date}}
{% endlocalize %}

# Date is shown and NOT localized
```

Why are the two results different? How can I make the localize tag localize correctly in combination with the date filter?

Comment: Can you share what happens if you do `{{ some_datetime_value | localize }}`

Comment: @BrianDestura, using the localize filter localizes the format correctly. I tried chaining it with the date filter (which returns only the date from a datetime object), but that didn't work.

Comment: Looks like a django bug with the date filter. I guess for now you can extract the date from `some_datetime_value` before passing it to the template to make it work and to avoid using the date filter

Comment: what happens if you don't use the date filter?

Comment: @user14665310, without the date filter localization works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As Brian Destura pointed out in the comments this looks like a Django bug.

Converting the datetime object to a date object before passing it to the template might work for a single object, but is very inconvenient if you have to access model fields that are stored as datetime (e.g. within for loops).

In case someone faces the same issue, a custom filter that converts the datetime object to a date object worked for me (this is actually what the in-built date filter is supposed to do).

custom_tags.py

```
@register.filter
def get_date(value):
    return value.date()
```

template.html

```
{% load i10n %}
{% load custom_tags %}

{% localize on %}
{{some_datetime_value|get_date}}
{% endlocalize %}

#localizes the format correctly
```